# Select columns from a table with a conditional join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for books and also a table for borrowed books. That table has a broughtBack column. Assume each book only has 1 copy. I want to make a query that will select all available book. If a book has no entry in the borrowed books table it means that it has never been borrowed so it is definitely available. But if it does then I need to check if it has been brought back.

Here is the query that I have so far.

```
SELECT [title]
FROM [Book] 
LEFT JOIN [Borrow] ON [Book].bookId = [Borrow].bookId 
WHERE [Borrow].broughtDate IS NOT NULL
```

The query works but only selects books that have already been borrowed and then returned. Is there a way I can make a single query that will do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify results where either the broughtDate is not null (book has been returned), or [Borrow].bookId is null (never been borrowed) this should do it.

```
SELECT [title]
FROM [Book] 
LEFT JOIN [Borrow] ON [Book].bookId = [Borrow].bookId 
WHERE [Borrow].broughtDate IS NOT NULL OR [Borrow].bookId  IS NULL
```

Be careful if a book can have multiple borrow records, as [Borrow].broughtDate IS NOT NULL will give wrong results. In this case you would need to only consider the latest Borrow record for each Book.

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT b.title
FROM Book b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM borrow bo
                  WHERE bo.bookId = b.bookId 
                        bo.broughtDate IS NULL
                 );
```

That is, no row exists in `Borrow` for the book with a `NULL` returned date.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select [title] from books where bookid in (select bookid from borrowed where broughtBack  = 1)
union
select [title] from books a where not exists (select bookid from borrowed b where a.bookid = b.bookid )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0f0e85951d6ffca50a38a3236d60d589)

```
SELECT *
FROM [Book] 
LEFT JOIN [Borrow] ON [Book].bookId = [Borrow].bookId 
WHERE [Borrow].bookId IS NULL 
OR  [Borrow].broughtDate IS NOT NULL
```